# Check if a foreign key value exists in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wanna check whether a foreign key value exists in another table. What I'm trying to do is: I have a table named *Gallery* and another one named *Posts*. Posts is the parent table, so Gallery bears the post_id foreign key.
On the **posts.php** page, since not every post has a gallery, I wanted to show a msg for each row, as in "has a gallery" or "does not have a gallery". For instance: post id 5 has a gallery and so does post number 10, but post id 1 doesn't have a gallery nor does post id 3. I'm thinking of a way like:  *Gallery* table,`if a gallery_id row has a 'null' value on column post_id, then echo "does not have a gallery." Else echo "has a gallery"`, on **posts.php**.
Is there a way of checking if a certain value exists in another table?

SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE `gallery` (
 `gallery_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `picture` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `gallery_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`gallery_id`),
 KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `gallery_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `posts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I just tried

```
<?php
    $checkGallery = new Read();      
    $checkGallery->performQuery('gallery', "WHERE post_id = :post_id", "id_post={$post_id}");      
    if($checkGallery->result()):        
      $affirmative = $checkGallery->result(); 
?>
```

and then

```
<td class="values">
  <?= (  $affirmative ? 'This post has a gallery!' : 'No gallery enrolled in this post' );?> 
</td>
```

Got no satisfactory results. It omitted certain rows instead of echoing "No gallery enrolled in this post"

Comment: You mean other than directly querying the `gallery` table?

Comment: And are there issues? Also, when adding new information with lots of code, it's better to edit that into the question. Comments aren't suitable for lengthy bits code (especially multiline).

Comment: In that extra code in the comment, where does `id_post` come into it? I'm not sure what your `performQuery()` function does, but shouldn't that read `post_id={$post_id}` rather than as you have it?

Comment: "It omitted certain rows" is not enough to go on. Provide a sample of data where it fails.

Comment: performQuery() does "SELECT * FROM table WHERE post_id = :post_id"
And id_post is actually post_id. My mistake, I misspelled it by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Boom! I got it.

I just performed a query "*SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_post = :id_post*" (considering we are calling the bindValue method on **posts.php**)and id_post = $id;
(*So, SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id_post = 5 or ... WHERE id = 3 and so on* and the results are store in the $checkGallery array.)

```
<?php
  if($checkGallery):
?>
    <td><?= This post has a gallery! ?></td>
<?php else: ?>
    <td><?= No gallery attached to this post.?></td>
<?php endif;?>
```

And each row returns either "*this post has a gallery*" or "*No gallery attached to this post*", all dynamically. Thanks